# Java Convolution

Tags: java, convolution

Hi I am in need of some help. I need to write a convolution method from scratch that takes in the following inputs: `int[][]` and `BufferedImage inputImage`. I can assume that the kernel has size 3x3.

My approach is to do the follow:

```
convolve inner pixels
convolve corner pixels
convolve outer pixels
```

In the program that I will post below I believe I convolve the inner pixels but I am a bit lost at how to convolve the corner and outer pixels. I am aware that corner pixels are at `(0,0)`, `(width-1,0)`, `(0, height-1)` and `(width-1,height-1)`. I think I know to how approach the problem but not sure how to execute that in writing though. Please to aware that I am very new to programming :/ Any assistance will be very helpful to me.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import com.programwithjava.basic.DrawingKit;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem28 {
     // maximum value of a sample
    private static final int MAX_VALUE = 255;
    //minimum value of a sample
    private static final int MIN_VALUE = 0; 

    public BufferedImage convolve(int[][] kernel, BufferedImage inputImage) {


    }

    public BufferedImage convolveInner(double center, BufferedImage inputImage) {
        int width = inputImage.getWidth();
        int height = inputImage.getHeight();

        BufferedImage inputImage1 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        //inner pixels
        for (int x = 1; x < width - 1; x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y < height - 1; y ++) {
                //get pixels at x, y
                int colorValue = inputImage.getRGB(x, y);
                Color pixelColor = new Color(colorValue);
                int red =  pixelColor.getRed() ;
                int green =  pixelColor.getGreen() ;
                int blue =  pixelColor.getBlue();

              int innerred =  (int) center*red;
              int innergreen =  (int) center*green;
              int innerblue =  (int) center*blue;

              Color newPixelColor = new Color(innerred, innergreen, innerblue);
              int newRgbvalue = newPixelColor.getRGB();
              inputImage1.setRGB(x, y, newRgbvalue);    
            }
        }
        return inputImage1;
    }

    public BufferedImage convolveEdge(double edge, BufferedImage inputImage) {
        int width = inputImage.getWidth();
        int height = inputImage.getHeight();

        BufferedImage inputImage2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        //inner pixels
        for (int x = 0; x < width - 1; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height - 1; y ++) {
                //get pixels at x, y
                int colorValue = inputImage.getRGB(x, y);
                Color pixelColor = new Color(colorValue);
                int red =  pixelColor.getRed() ;
                int green =  pixelColor.getGreen() ;
                int blue =  pixelColor.getBlue();

              int innerred =  (int) edge*red;
              int innergreen =  (int) edge*green;
              int innerblue =  (int) edge*blue;

              Color newPixelColor = new Color(innerred, innergreen, innerblue);
              int newRgbvalue = newPixelColor.getRGB();
              inputImage2.setRGB(x, y, newRgbvalue);    
            }
        }
        return inputImage2;
    }

    public BufferedImage convolveCorner(double corner, BufferedImage inputImage) {
        int width = inputImage.getWidth();
        int height = inputImage.getHeight();

        BufferedImage inputImage3 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        //inner pixels
        for (int x = 0; x < width - 1; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height - 1; y ++) {
                //get pixels at x, y
                int colorValue = inputImage.getRGB(x, y);
                Color pixelColor = new Color(colorValue);
                int red =  pixelColor.getRed() ;
                int green =  pixelColor.getGreen() ;
                int blue =  pixelColor.getBlue();

              int innerred =  (int) corner*red;
              int innergreen =  (int) corner*green;
              int innerblue =  (int) corner*blue;

              Color newPixelColor = new Color(innerred, innergreen, innerblue);
              int newRgbvalue = newPixelColor.getRGB();
              inputImage3.setRGB(x, y, newRgbvalue);    
            }
        }
        return inputImage3;
    }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawingKit dk = new DrawingKit("Compositor", 1000, 1000);
    BufferedImage p1 = dk.loadPicture("image/pattern1.jpg");
    Problem28 c = new Problem28();
    BufferedImage p5 = c.convolve();
    dk.drawPicture(p5, 0, 100);
  }
}
```

I changed the code a bit but the output comes out as black. What did I do wrong:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import com.programwithjava.basic.DrawingKit;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem28 {
    // maximum value of a sample
    private static final int MAX_VALUE = 255;
    //minimum value of a sample
    private static final int MIN_VALUE = 0; 


    public BufferedImage convolve(int[][] kernel, BufferedImage inputImage) {


        int width = inputImage.getWidth();
        int height = inputImage.getHeight();

        BufferedImage inputImage1 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        //for every pixel
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x ++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y ++) {

                int colorValue = inputImage.getRGB(x,y);
                Color pixelColor = new Color(colorValue);
                int red = pixelColor.getRed();
                int green = pixelColor.getGreen();
                int blue = pixelColor.getBlue();

                double gray = 0;

                //multiply every value of kernel with corresponding image pixel
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j ++) {

                        int imageX = (x - 3/2 + i + width) % width;
                        int imageY = (x -3/2 + j + height) % height;


                        int RGB = inputImage.getRGB(imageX, imageY);
                        int GRAY = (RGB) & 0xff;

                        gray += (GRAY*kernel[i][j]);

                    }
                }
                int out;
                out = (int) Math.min(Math.max(gray * 1, 0), 255);
                inputImage1.setRGB(x, y, new Color(out,out,out).getRGB());
            }
        }
        return inputImage1;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] newArray = {{1/9, 1/9, 1/9}, {1/9, 1/9, 1/9}, {1/9, 1/9, 1/9}};
    DrawingKit dk = new DrawingKit("Problem28", 1000, 1000);
    BufferedImage p1 = dk.loadPicture("image/pattern1.jpg");
    Problem28 c = new Problem28();
    BufferedImage p2 = c.convolve(newArray, p1);
    dk.drawPicture(p2, 0, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome ewuzz!  I wrote a convolution using CUDA about a week ago, and the majority of my experience is with Java, so I feel qualified to provide advice for this problem.

Rather than writing all of the code for you, the best way to solve this large program is to discuss individual elements.  You mentioned you are `very new to programming`.  As the programs you write become more complex, it's essential to write small working snippets before combining them into a large successful program (or iteratively add snippets).  With this being said, it's already apparent you're trying to debug a ~100 line program, and this approach will cost you time in most cases.

The first point to discuss is the general approach you mentioned.  If you think about the program, what is the simplest and most repeated step?  Obviously this is the kernel/mask step, so we can start from here.  When you convolute each pixel, you are performing a similar option, regardless of the position (corner, edge, inside).  While there are special steps necessary for these [edge cases](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjSz5C5y9DSAhVJ7mMKHe1oAjwQFghKMAs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEdge_case&usg=AFQjCNFYAsJeBs8WqG2YrlC2DoqG_ouU9Q&sig2=W4K7tLoCiQmI1ETszdn7EQ), they share similar underlying steps.  If you try to write code for each of these cases separately, you will have to update the code in multiple (three) places with each adjustment and it will make the whole program more difficult to grasp.

To support my point above, here's what happened when I pasted your code into [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).  This illustrates the (yellow) red flag of using the same code in multiple places:

[image]

The concrete way to fix this problem is to combine the three convolve methods into a single one and use if statements for edge-cases as necessary.

Our pseudocode with this change:

```
convolve(kernel, inputImage)
   for each pixel in the image
      convolve the single pixel and check edge cases
   endfor
end
```

That seems pretty basic right?  If we are able to successfully `check edge cases`, then this extremely simple logic will work.  The reason I left it so general above to show how `convolve the single pixel and check edge cases` is logically grouped.  This means it's a good candidate for extracting a method, which could look like:

```
private void convolvePixel(int x, int y, int[][] kernel, BufferedImage input, BufferedImage output)
```

Now to implement our method above, we will need to break it into a few steps, which we may then break into more steps if necessary.  We'll need to look at the input image, if possible for each pixel accumulate the values using the kernel, and then set this in the output image.  For brevity I will only write pseudocode from here.

```
convolvePixel(x, y, kernel, input, output)
   accumulation = 0
   for each row of kernel applicable pixels
      for each column of kernel applicable pixels
         if this neighboring pixel location is within the image boundaries then
            input color = get the color at this neighboring pixel
            adjusted value = input color * relative kernel mask value
            accumulation += adjusted value
         else
            //handle this somehow, mentioned below
         endif
      endfor
   endfor
   set output pixel as accumulation, assuming this convolution method does not require normalization
end
```

The pseudocode above is already relatively long.  When implementing you could write methods for the `if` and the `else` cases, but it you should be fine with this structure.

There are a few ways to handle the edge case of the `else` above.  Your assignment probably specifies a requirement, but the fancy way is to `tile` around, and pretend like there's another instance of the same image next to this input image.  Wikipedia explains three possibilities:

1. Extend - The nearest border pixels are conceptually extended as far as necessary to provide values for the convolution. Corner pixels are extended in 90° wedges. Other edge pixels are extended in lines.
2. Wrap - (The method I mentioned) The image is conceptually wrapped (or tiled) and values are taken from the opposite edge or corner.
3. Crop - Any pixel in the output image which would require values from beyond the edge is skipped. This method can result in the output image being slightly smaller, with the edges having been cropped.

A huge part of becoming a successful programmer is researching on your own.  If you read about these methods, work through them on paper, run your `convolvePixel` method on single pixels, and compare the output to your results by hand, you will find success.

Summary:

1. Start by cleaning-up your code before anything.
2. Group the same code into one place.
3. Hammer out a small chunk (convolving a single pixel).  Print out the result and the input values and verify they are correct.
4. Draw out edge/corner cases.
5. Read about ways to solve edge cases and decide what fits your needs.
6. Try implementing the `else` case through the same form of testing.
7. Call your `convolveImage` method with the loop, using the `convolvePixel` method you know works.  Done!

You can look up pseudocode and even specific code to solve the exact problem, so I focused on providing general insight and strategies I have developed through my degree and personal experience.  Good luck and please let me know if you want to discuss anything else in the comments below.

[Java code for multiple blurs via convolution.](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html)